# angularjs drop-down menu with static options appears empty

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am currently trying to make a static drop-down menu to see how it works before using dynamic values, but it doesn't even work. Here is my js file:

```
<td ng-show="!attributed">
    <form method="post" action="/tache/add">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{task.id}}" />
        <select name="attribution" data-ng-options="o.nom for o in options"
            data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
        <input type="submit" value="Attribute" />
    </form>
</td>
```

And here is the controller's content corresponding to this part of the page:

```
$scope.options = [{ nom: "a", id: 1 }, { nom: "b", id: 2 }];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];
```

None of these names appear in the drop-down menu, and when I click to see all options, there's just a small and white menu with one empty choice. Does anyone know where my mistake is ?

Comment: Actually your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/tqV8y/
See error somewhere else (or give us fiddle/plunker).

Comment: Yes your code is working fine.